# Email Id validation for real or not using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

is it possible to validate a Email in the way whether it is an existing emailid(that it is in use, not fake) by using any builtin functions in jQuery.

Then some website forms recognize if non-existing id's are entered. Is it that when they try to send confirmation mail, & if it's not sent successfully, they come to know as it's a fake one?

Comment: If you have access to all emails addresses in the world then yes

Comment: There are more than 1000 of email provider is there . Then you have to contact each email provider and check is that email id belongs to your server ? :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, email validation using a built-in jQuery function is not going to be an option for you; it's built to support a wide range of functionality and this is considered niche.

Email validation can take many shapes; I'll try to summarize them here, in order of accuracy / reliability:

1. It matches a regular expression (bad) or is validated according to RFC2822 (good) - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1
2. The domain part of the email address has at least one associated MX record; if not present, the associated A (IPv4) / AAAA (IPv6) record should be used (less reliable though) - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.5
3. The established connection with a listed mail exchange server responds positively to an `RCPT TO:` command - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.1.3
4. A confirmation email is sent and didn't bounce directly (hard bounce)
5. A confirmation email was received by the intended recipient and they clicked the confirmation link therein or otherwise confirmed reception of the email.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way *at all* to verify mailbox validity with any acceptable accuracy. Many (if not most) email providers do not support recipient verification.